# C# Keep Asynchronous Socket open

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I have an asynchronous server and several asynchronous clients connecting to it. The client should start the connection and keep this connection open until it terminates so that it can send and receive data on demand.

I am using the Asynchronous client and server code in:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I've made the IPEndpoint and Socket class objects so that they can be called everywhere in the class:

```
static IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"),12345);

static Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream,ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

I've also commented out the socket closure in the StartClient() function and did the same on the server:

```
// Client
// Release the socket.
client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
client.Close();

// Server
handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
handler.Close();
```

Then I called the client's

```
Send(Socket client, String data) like this:

Send(client,"This is test 1<EOF>");
sendDone.WaitOne();

Receive(client);
receiveDone.WaitOne();

Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}",response);
```

but I get all kinds of exceptions, like "Socket is null".

How can I start a connection to the server, keep this connection open indefinitely and use it from any part of my code?

Comment: There's not enough information here to give you a real answer. `Socket is null` means that you're passing in a null reference to the `Send` method. We can't see how you're calling it, though - so we're unable to give any guidance.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it, I've updated my question with the call to Send().